# DataFrame filter with multiple columns not working using && operator in Spark 2.2 (scala)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using a dataframe in spark 2.2 and loaded data there.I am using && operator in Filter function that is using multiple columns. The error is saying  error: value && is not a member of String

Here is my code.

```
scala> val orders = spark.sparkContext.textFile("D:\\SparkExamples\\retail_db\\orders\\part-00000")                                                            

scala> import java.sql.Timestamp

scala> val ordersMap = orders.map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toInt,Timestamp.valueOf(x.split(",")(1)),x.split(",")(2).toInt,x.split(",")(3)))

scala> val ordersSchema = ordersMap.toDF("order_id","order_date","order_customer_id","order_status")
```

Below filter is working correctly -

```
ordersSchema.select($"*").filter($"order_status"=== "COMPLETE").show
```

But when I put two columns in filter with && like below -

```
scala> ordersSchema.select($"*").filter($"order_status"!== "COMPLETE" && $"order_date" === "2013-07-25 00:00:00").show
<console>:34: error: value && is not a member of String
       ordersSchema.select($"*").filter($"order_status"!== "COMPLETE" && $"order_date" === "2013-07-25 00:00:00").show
```

Error is coming out. Any pointer?

Comment: replace !== with =!= this should work

Comment: replace `&&` with `and`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` is not a valid logical operator for spark `Columns`, use `and` instead:

```
ordersSchema.select($"*").filter($"order_status" =!= "COMPLETE" and $"order_date" === "2013-07-25 00:00:00").show
```